# Flags in VB6 does not return a correct value

Tags: vb6, enums, bitflags

I am currently trying to use a bit flag enum in a VB6 / COM project.
However, when trying to read values from the enum, I get inconsistent results.

Here is the enum definition :

```
Enum Fruits
    None = 0
    Apple = 1
    Strawberry = 2
    Lemon = 4
End Enum
```

I have an object which exposes a property of type Fruits

```
Public Get AvailableFruits as Fruits
```

The code that should be able to read the value is used to show / hide a label depending on the values of each bit of the enum :

```
lblAppleAvailable.Visible = basket.AvailableFruits And Fruits.Apple
```

When this code is executed and I have `basket.AvailableFruits = 0`, I get True as result.

Any idea of what could cause this behavior ?

Edit :

I have tried with the different values of the enum :

```
basket.AvailableFruits = 0
basket.AvailableFruits And Apple        // Returns True
basket.AvailableFruits And Strawberry   // Returns True
basket.AvailableFruits And Lemon        // Returns False
```

As a side node, when debugging the code, If I put the expression in a watch expression, I get the correct value; but when the expression is evaluated in my code, it still returns True.

I tried using a different check syntax :

```
(basket.AvailableFruits And Fruits.Apple) = Fruits.Apple
```

Still getting True when `basket.AvailableFruits = 0` :-(

**Solution**

After having tested different solutions, I have been able to narrow the problem to the COM component.
The original coder of this component had a pointer set to 0 instead of returning 0 as a value, which caused the problem when trying to read the value.

I have selected FlipScript answer because of the helper function which seems a good tip to improve the readability of the code.

Comment: What is your code for `basket.AvailableFruits`?

Comment: @LBT : I don't have access to the real code of the property, it is part of a COM object coded in C++.

Comment: So, when AvailableFruits = 0, then in the Apple case (0 AND 1) = True?  Yet in the Lemon case (0 AND 4) = False?  Hmmm.... There might be something more than bitfield checking going on here...

Comment: I had the opportunity to check the code of the property : it is currently not implemented and always returns 0.

Comment: Haha, well at least now you know how to write your end of the code when it finally gets implemented!

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain the strange result I got with 1,2 & 4 tests :-(

Comment: I recommend you check that you're definitely seeing this behaviour. It sounds impossible to me. Check whether there's any other code that sets the label visibility, whether you're changing the correct label... If you're really getting this behaviour I can only think that your C COM object is writing to a bad pointer and totally screwing the VB6 runtime. Theoretically possible for that to cause something this weird, but I've not seen it happen.

Comment: Ought one to have `basket.AvailableFruits = 0`, since 0 isn't a value for the `Fruits` enumeration?

Comment: @Brian Hooper : My bad, the enumeration does have a value for 0, but I did not include it in my question. Corrected !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To test the value of the flag, use something like this:

```
lblAppleAvailable.Visible = (basket.AvailableFruits And Fruits.Apple) = Fruits.Apple
```

After you do the "AND", you still need to see if the resulting value equals the flag value (or anything other than 0, really).

You could also create a little helper function:

```
Private Function HasFruitFlag(Check As Fruits, Flag As Fruits) As Boolean
    HasFruitFlag (Check And Flag) = Flag
End Function
```

And you could call it like this:

```
lblAppleAvailable.Visible = HasFruitFlag(basket.AvailableFruits, Fruits.Apple)
```

Comment: +1 this is correct. You just beat me to posting the same thing.

Comment: I tried to compare the resulting value with 0 (((basket.AvailableFruits And Fruits.Apple) <> 0), but without success. Will try your method though.

Comment: I think this is wrong. In the original code, VB6 will implicitly coerce the integer result of the bitwise And operation to a Boolean. Zero will be converted to False, and any non-zero value will be converted to True. This code change won't alter the result of the expression.

Comment: "I had the opportunity to check the code of the property : it is currently not implemented and always returns 0." - lol.  Well, that explains why the flag checking isn't working!  Anyway, when you need a helper function to do the job once that property gets fixed, this should do it.

Comment: MarkJ - I have no idea what you meant...  VB6 does not implicity coerce integers that have had bitwise operations performed to Booleans.  The helper function that I wrote above is an equality comparison that explicity returns a boolean.

Comment: I just tried this solution, and it didn't solve the problem. I'll try to have a look on the property getter to see if something is going on there.

Comment: @FlipScript : Well, even if I get 0 at each call, it does not explain why I get True when evaluating the expression (1 And 0) <> 0 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a local var

```
    Dim LocalFruits As Fruits

    LocalFruits = basket.AvailableFruits
    Debug.Print (LocalFruits And Apple) <> 0
    Debug.Print (LocalFruits And Strawberry) <> 0
    Debug.Print (LocalFruits And Lemon) <> 0
```

Also, you might want to use a less error-prone declaration of the enum like this

```
Enum Fruits
    Apple = 2 ^ 0
    Strawberry = 2 ^ 1
    Lemon = 2 ^ 2
End Enum
```